# Dúvida na busca de um id com o foreach no php

Tags: php, html, array, query, foreach

Boa noite pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um código de trabalho de conclusão de curso e estou com uma dúvida. Tenho uma tabela usuários e veículos, uso o Inner Join no select e logo em seguida os exibo utilizando o foreach. Porém, ocorre que em cada campo o usuário pode escolher ou alterar o usuário ou excluí-lo (envio os dados de acordo com o id selecionado utilizando o SESSION). [image: 1]]
Porém, aí está o problema! Quando eu tento passar o id código que desejo modificar, ele apenas pega o último id ao invés do respectivo código.
Por exemplo: Desejo excluir o código 1, aperto em excluir, o sistema exclui o código 3 ao invés do 1.

Como minha exibição está:

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Placa</th>
        <th>Modelo</th>
        <th>Cor</th>
        <th>Fabricante</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($dados as $linha):
        $id = $linha[0];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $linha[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[3]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[4]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[5]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[6]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[7]; ?></td>
        <td><a name="altera" onclick="
         <?php
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['alterar'] = 'usuario';
          ?>" href="alterar.php">Alterar</a></td>
        <td><a name="excluir" onclick="
         <?php
            $_SESSION['excluir'] = 'usuario';
         ?>" href="processaexcluir.php">Excluir</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        }
        $id++;
        endforeach;
    ?>
    </table>
```

Gostaria de saber se há algum meio de buscar um índice específico no foreach ou se há algum outro modo de fazê-lo. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: tente usar apenas um, dessa forma:  <td><?php echo $linha; ?></td> exclua os demais, não é necessário fazer o loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xubilau, o problema é que a variável global '$_SESSION['id'] = $id;' está sempre sendo atribuída ao último id, e por isso está tendo esse erro, tente usar o GET do php.

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Placa</th>
        <th>Modelo</th>
        <th>Cor</th>
        <th>Fabricante</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($dados as $linha):
        $id = $linha[0];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $linha[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[3]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[4]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[5]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[6]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linha[7]; ?></td>
        <td><a name="altera" href="alterar.php?CarroId=<?php echo $linha[0]; ?>">Alterar</a></td>
        <td><a name="excluir" href="processaexcluir.php?CarroId=<?php echo $linha[0]; ?>">Excluir</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        }
        $id++;
        endforeach;
    ?>
    </table>
```

Após isso, no arquivo PHP, leia o valor que foi passado pela URL utilizando o GET dessa maneira:

```html
<?php
$carroId = $_GET['CarroId'];

...
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu tentei fazer mudanças no código para ver se conseguia realizar de outro modo utilizando forms no alterar e excluir, porém nenhum estava dando por erros no javascript que eu desconhecia. Agora utilizando sua modificação consegui fazer com que desse certo. Muito obrigado.